# Excessive CPU RAM being used by Pytorch even inside .cuda() mode

Tags: python, pytorch

I am having issue with excessive CPU RAM usage with [this coding](https://github.com/promach/gdas) even inside *.cuda()* mode

Could anyone advise ?

Comment: 514 lines of code at the end of a github link isn't really very useful to anyone. If you need help you are going to have to provide an [MCVE] here, including what you think "excessive" is....

Comment: @talonmies minimal example is bit difficult in this case,  excessive is 8GB CPU RAM being utilized as being tracked using "free" linux terminal command as compared to just 600MB GPU RAM used as tracked using "nvidia-smi"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is now [solved using this github commit](https://github.com/promach/gdas/commit/9f1e0d24e077d094ebe21f71b6a1d3b5227b8e8b)